# Uploading articles to Google Scholar

Tags: publications, paper-submission

How to upload my journal articles to Google Scholar and get it appeared immediately?

Answer (score 6):

Log in, go to your profile, click the "+" icon, and select "Add article manually". Then fill in the details and it will appear on your profile immediately.

However you cannot upload a pdf to Google Scholar or anything like that. Google Scholar is not a repository. And the citations will only appear after the crawler finds it on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how to ensure Google Scholar finds the PDF in short time? I have one paper already on the journal home page as well as on Scopus. But the PDF is not available on Scholar after one month now.

Comment: @Esen contact google scholar for detailed help.

Comment: Crawler need few days, usually 5 days is enough for it to find a paper/article...

Comment: @SolarMike One does not simply "contact Google", unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can not upload anything directly to Google Scholar. However, if you upload your document to an appropriate repository that assigns you a doi (a preprint server, zenodo, OSF, etc), it will appear on your GS in a matter of days. If you have in mind something like an accepted version of a paper, it will depend on how much time the editorial team requires to assign the doi and make the document public.