# How can we add a missing article in Google Scholar?

Tags: journals, google-scholar

We are using OJS 3 and all of our articles are in Google Scholar, except one we published in 2020. How can we add it, is there any solution?

We have removed that article one time from the system due to major changes and then published it again after a few days. So what is the solution now to add in Google Scholar?

Comment: We seem to routinely get questions on Google Scholar, particularly since how it actually works is opaque and there is no help available from them. But, we are not Google and have no insight into how it works...

Comment: You can't manually add papers to the Google scholar index if that's what your asking, e.g., see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/143962/19607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you removed the paper once and added it again, it may take [several weeks](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#crawl) for the Google crawler bot to re-crawl your newly added article. If you are using OJS, I believe it is by default [allows Google](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) bots to index articles in Google scholars.

A similar situation happened for me once, and it took almost a year for the article to appear in Scholar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes we are using ojs and that article removed once and published again. But now almost completed one year and still not in google scholar why ? oTHers our articles are okay in google scholar.

Comment: @AhsanNazir Unfortunetly, the algorithm behind Google Scholar is a mystery! I don't know if it helps, but I suggest you submit your sitemap to Google via Webmasters tool. If you are using OJS, sitemap can be found in http(s)://yourdomain.com/index.php/ABC/sitemap. It usually shouldn't take more than a couple of months. Maybe it pushes the Google Scholar crawler bot to re-crawl the papers. There is also a "Google Scholar Inclusion Request" form, where you can manually send your journal's page to Google, but I'm not sure if it works or not: https://support.google.com/scholar/troubleshooter/23941

Comment: Thanks dear, we cannot add manually ? all details with PDF like other papers ?

Comment: @AhsanNazir Unfortunately you can't add links/pdfs when you are adding paper manually in Google Scholar.

Comment: You mean we just need to wait for that otherwise no solution for this, Thanks dear.

Comment: @AhsanNazir Try adding sitemap using Google webmasters tools. Maybe it helps. Other than that I’m afraid there is not much you can do than waiting.

Comment: Sir are you using OJS too ? we have some issue can you help. Like if email send from our system to the author. In email details showing that email send via sr33...hosting.eu. So we want to replace this address with our journal. How we can ?

Comment: @AhsanNazir You should ask this in an OJS forum.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google Scholar profile and click the + icon in the heading at the top of the list of your publications.  Click "Add article manually" and you'll get a popup where you can fill in the details.

Comment: Thanks but in mannual we cannot add PDF and all details ? can you help in this ?

Comment: The article has to have been published somewhere.

Comment: The article already published in 2020. But only not appear on google scholar, any solution

Comment: It the article has been published, just enter the details in the popup.

Comment: thanks can you share me link where to add details in popup.

Comment: You need to create a Google scholar profile.  Have you done that?  Once you've done that, go to your profile and you'll see the list of your pubs they know about.  The + button to open the popup will be in the heading at the top of the list.